# Tensorflow graph nodes are exchange

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorboard, object-detection-api

I have trained a model with fine-tuning pre-trained model `ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018`. Here, I have used the exact same pipeline.config file for training which is available inside `ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018` pre-trained folder.
I have only removed the `batch_norm_trainable: true` flag and changed the number of classes (4).
After training the model with my custom datasets with 4 classes, I found `concat` and `concat_1` nodes get exchange with each other.
Pre-trained model has
`| concat | 1x1917x1x4 |`
after-training it becomes
`| concat | 1x1917x5 |`
I have attached both tensorboard graph visualisation images. First image is pre-trained graph `ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018`.
[image]
[image]

The node exchanges can be seen on the rightmost corner of the image. As in the pre-trained graph, `Postprocess layer` connect with `concat_1` and `Squeeeze` connect with `concat`. But after the training, the graph shows completely reverse. Like `Prosprocess layer` connect with `concat` and `Squeeeze` connect with `concat_1`.
Further, I also found in the pre-trained model graph that the `Preprocessor` takes input `ToFloat` while after training the graph shows Cast as an input to `Preprocessor`.
I have fed the input to the model as `tfrecords`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably, the difference is not in the graph, but simply in the names of the nodes, i.e. nodes `concat` and `concat_1` on the left are the same nodes as resp. `concat_1` and `concat` on the right.

The thing is, when you don't provide an explicit name to a node, tensorflow needs to come up with one, and it's naming convention is rather uninventive. The first time it needs to name a node, it does so with its type. When it encounter the situation again, it simply add `_` + an increasing number to the name.

Take this example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (1,), name='x')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (1,), name='y')
z = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (1,), name='z')

xy = tf.concat([x, y], axis=0)  # named 'concat'
xz = tf.concat([x, z], axis=0)  # named 'concat_1'
```

The graph looks like this:

[image]

Now if we construct the *same* graph, but this time creating `xz` before `xy`, we get the following graph:

[image]

So the graph did not really change -- only the names did. This is probably what happened in your case: the same operations were created but not in the same order.

The fact that names changed for stateless nodes like `concat` is unimportant, because no weights will be misrouted when loading a saved model for example. Nonetheless, if naming stability is important for you, you could either give explicit names to your operations or place them in distinct scopes:

```
xy = tf.concat([x, y], axis=0, name='xy')
xz = tf.concat([x, z], axis=0, name='xz')
```

[image]

It is much more problematic if *variables* switch name. This is one of the reason why `tf.get_variable` -- which forces variables to have a name and raises an error when a name conflict occurs -- was the preferred way of dealing with variables in the pre-TF2 era.

Comment: Hi @P-Gn, I agreed with your explanation for node name changes in TF, but since i am training my model with pre-trained model thus with the name its changes output shape also. For example: Pre-trained model has  `| concat | 1x1917x1x4 |` after-training it becomes `| concat | 1x1917x5 |`. Probably you can have a look detailed explanation (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/8362)

Comment: What about `concat_1`? What are the size before/after?

Comment: Same things happens with concat_1, Pre-trained model has `| concat_1 | 1x1917x91 |` after-training it becomes `| concat_1 |1x1917x1x4  |`. More info about shapes you can see in below link (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/8356). What, i understand graph changed the node name along with shapes.

Comment: This could be due to the fact that you modified the trained model. How did you do it?

Comment: No i have not change anything in the trained network, except: number of classes(`90 to 4`) and input and eval tf records and label map. All the default setting i am using, [tensorflow models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs) `ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.config` file.

Comment: Well your change in the number of classes certainly is consistent with the change in the shape of `concat_1` (`1x1917x91` -> `1x1917x5`). This comforts the idea you introduced those changes.

Comment: In my trained model `concat_1` shape should be `1x1917x5 ` however its `1x1917x1x4`. (`1x1917x5 ` shape has taken place in `concat`) That's what my original question. `concat` and `concat_1` nodes exchange along with shapes.

Comment: Also i believe due to change in number of classes should not impact the shape of the node. This can impact in numbers such `(1x1917x91 -> 1x1917x5)` but not `(1x1917x91 -> 1x1917x1x4)`.